# Modifying methods across classes

Tags: java, hook

I am rather sure that this is impossible, but I think I might as well try. I have some existing code which I do not own, and I want to keep my code completely seperate, say this was the original class

```
public class myClass
{
    public static void doStuffs()
        {
             x = x + 1;
        }
}
```

and the other class had:

```
public static void setData()
       {
             //Set the data
       }
```

Is it possible to call doStuffs() when setData() is called without modifying the the actual setData() method? If so how?

Comment: AspectJ seems like an answer for your problem

Comment: Only with byte code weaving.  This is usually only a good idea if you cannot touch the code or need to make a change across allot of code (so changing it is not practical)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using [Javaassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).
You can modify bytecode at runtime using this lib

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through byte code instrumentation:
[ByteCodeInstrumentation](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=585)

There are several libraries to help like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist) etc